# How can I add and retrieve elements in a Ruby Hash using readers and setters

Tags: ruby, hash, attr-accessor

I want to be able to add and retrieve elements to a hash via getters and setters.
Here is my class

```
class Config

  attr_reader :p1, :p2, :p4

  def initialize(options={})
    options.each do |k,v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
    end
  end

end
```

Currently I am only able to add and retrieve elements with keys as `p1, p2 and p3`

If I try adding new elements e.g

```
> a = Config.new({name: "kevin"})
return value is
=> #<Config:0x000000000a4422a8 @name="kevin">
```

on trying to access the name

```
> a.name
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<Config:0x000000000a4422a8 @name="kevin">
```

How can I access the name value with 
`a.name` to get `"Kevin"`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want a data struct storing like hash, maybe you can try `OpenStruct`

For example:

```
require 'ostruct'

class Config < OpenStruct
  # some other methods
end
```

Than you can do this

```
hash_input = { name: "kevin", gender: "male" }
config = Config.new(hash_input)
config.name
#=> "kevin"
```

For more detail about `OpenStruct`, you can checkout [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
class Config    
  def initialize(options={})
    options.each do |k,v|
      singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, k)
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
    end
  end
end
```

This will allow you to define different set of readers for each instance of Config class (if this is your intention).  For example:

```
c1 = Config.new(test1: "test1")
#=> #<Config:0x0000000c3a82c8 @test1="test1">
c2 = Config.new(test2: "test2")
#=> #<Config:0x0000000b7013d0 @test2="test2">
c1.test1
#=> "test1"
c1.test2
# NoMethodError: undefined method `test2' for #<Config:0x0000000c3a82c8 @test1="test1">
# from (pry):59:in `<main>'
c2.test2
#=> "test2"
c2.test1
# NoMethodError: undefined method `test1' for #<Config:0x0000000b7013d0 @test2="test2">
# from (pry):61:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Why use `send`? `attr_reader` is a public method. `singleton_class.attr_reader k` would do just fine.

Comment: `NoMethodError: private method `attr_reader' called for #<Class:#<Config:0x00000002e8cd88>>`.  For some reason it's complaining about it.

Comment: I get the same error with Ruby 2.4, however it works with Ruby 2.5 and higher. I didn't know it was private before 2.5.